# How to delete audio file that is already used by mediaElement (in WPF-C#)?

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, mediaelement

Now I have to code a module that auto-generate a sound file (result.mp3) after each process. I use MediaElement in WPF to make audio and slider buttons.

In each process, I have to overwrite the file result.mp3. However, each time I attend to delete the result.mp3 (has used after listening by mediaElement), the program oftens bring an exception: access denied. Certainly, I also reset new Url to stop the MediaElement whenever I generate new audio file.

```
mediaElement.Stop();
mediaElement.Source=new Uri("result.mp3");
mediaElement.Start();
```

How can I fix that error?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have solution to fix this error.

You have to close mediaElement in these events:
1. The Stop button.
2. The MediaElement_End event

```
   private void stopButton_Event()
        {
            fileIsPlaying = false;
            playtimer.Stop();
            mediaElement.Stop();
            mediaElement.Close();
            seekSlider.Value = 0;
            currentTimeTextBlock.Content = "00:00";
            buttonPlay.Content = "Play";
        }
```

I still don't know what causes this error